# Create an SQL view command using the in command

Tags: mysql, sql, view, create-view

I am writing a create view program in SQL and my last create view statement is giving me some trouble. For this view statement I want to retrieve all the uid from all universities in the city of columbia. Then I want to use a sub query to get the information for the first name and last name of the person. The official description is as follows

```
Write a query that returns only the uid value for all universities in the city Columbia. Then use 
that query with an IN sub-query expression to retrieve the first and last names for all people that  
go to school in Columbias
```

I will now post the code that I wrote for the create table statement, then I will post the two tables that I will be using for the view statement. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
CREATE VIEW inn AS
SELECT a.uid
FROM letsdoit.university as a
WHERE b.fname, b.lname IN(SELECT b.fname, b.lname FROM letsdoit.person as b WHERE (a.city = "Columbia"));
```

The tables are

```
               Table "letsdoit.university"
     Column      |         Type          |                        Modifiers                         
-----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------
 uid             | integer               | not null default nextval('university) uid_seq'::regclass)
 university_name | character varying(50) | 
 city            | character varying(50) | 



            Table "letsdoit.person"
 Column |         Type          |                      Modifiers                
--------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------
 pid    | integer               | not null default nextval('person_pid_seq'::reg class)
 uid    | integer               | 
 fname  | character varying(25) | not null
 lname  | character varying(25) | not null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the problem statement it looks like the first query you are instructed to create should be the subquery for the IN, and that should be used as criteria to find the first and last names for people at that university (because UID is on both PERSON and UNIVERSITY), so your view would be like this:

```
create view inn as
select fname, lname
  from letsdoit.person
 where uid in (select uid from letsdoit.university where city = 'Columbia')
```